# SQL columns comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Using sql and have a few different tables I've joined together to give me some data based on a specific firm name.  Now I've created a temp table to see if that firm has responded to me in the past or not.  What I thought I could do was select the second table in the where clause to give me all the firms like the firms from my other two tables. Kept getting errors from that select list.  Joining the tables was dropping or excluding some records.  I also thought maybe using a cte table to get the data then try and compare it in my where clause but that gave me errors also.

Here is the error

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Here is the code

```
select 
*
```

from
(
    select
        data_year,
        data_qtr,
        firm_ui_acct,
        firm_legal_name,
        branch_trade_name,
        branch_cnty,
        data_empl
    from r_firm f
        inner join r_branch b
            on f.firm_ui_acct = b.branch_ui_acct 
        inner join r_data d
            on b.branch_id = d.branch_id
    where d.data_year = 2013
        and d.data_qtr = 2
)nm
    inner join cealookup..r_region_matrix mtx
        on nm.branch_cnty = mtx.county_id

where mtx.region_code = 7 
    and mtx.region_type = 2
    and 
    (
        ltrim(branch_trade_name) like (select firmname from TempData..NTVC_Big_Data_Survey)

`OR

    ltrim(firm_legal_name) like (select firmname from TempData..NTVC_Big_Data_Survey)
)`

Comment: whats the error saying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comparison is causing it: 
`ltrim(branch_trade_name) like (select firmname from TempData..NTVC_Big_Data_Survey)`. 
The select in there is returning multiple rows.  If you replace the `LIKE` with an `IN`, it will run.  Not sure if that will actually return the desired results, but it will run.

You will get this error when using almost any operator with a sub-query that returns multiple rows.  Here is some useful info on this from MS:
[Clicky!](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190609%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)